# ie removeAttr title problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

When i try to remove the attr title from an element it deletes it the second time i hover the element.

This problem only occurs in internet explorer.

here's the code:

```
$('span').live({"mouseover": function(){
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeoutId'));
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).removeAttr("title");
    if($(this).children('.tip-hover').length > 0){
        if($(this).children('.tip-hover').is(':visible') == false){
            $(document).find('.tip-hover').hide();
            $(this).children('.tip-hover').fadeIn(100);
        }else{
            $(document).find('.tip-hover').hide();
            $(this).children('.tip-hover').show();
        }
    }else{

        if(title != false){
            var height = $(this).css('line-height') + 2;
            $(this).prepend('<div class="tip-hover"><div class="tip-top"></div><div class="tip-hover-wrap"><div class="tip-hover-inner">' + title + '</div></div></div>');
            $(this).children('.tip-hover').css("margin-top", height + "px");
            var width = $(this).width() / 2;
            $(this).children('.tip-hover').css("padding-left",width+"px");
        }
    }

},
    "mouseout": function() {
        var someelement = this;
        var timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){ $(someelement).find(".tip-hover").fadeOut("slow");}, 350);
        $(someelement).data('timeoutId', timeoutId);
    }
});
```

Comment: jQuery 101: Store a reference to $(this) into a variable so you do not have to keep looking it up $() is expensive.

Comment: Also `if(title != false)` is never going to going to be false unless something is setting it to a Boolean false value. Removing an attribute does not produce false.

Comment: thanx for that tip! changed it right! How would i do it than? check if title exists!

Comment: Why would you use `$(document).find('.tip-hover')`? What’s wrong with `$('.tip-hover')`?

Comment: A bad habit i guess! Although i have been working with jquery for a long time i learn new things every time i encounter a problem! That is a good thing i guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it displays the `title` the first time is because you only remove the `title` attribute on `mouseover`. By then, it’s already too late!

I would suggest removing the title attributes outside of your event handler, as soon as the document is loaded, saving a backup in a custom `data-*` attribute.

```
$(function() {
  $('span').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this
      .data('title', $this.attr('title'))
      .removeAttr('title');
  });
});
```

Then, in your code, instead of…

```
var title = $(this).attr('title');
```

Use:

```
var title = $(this).data('title');
```

Comment: would it be better if i prepend the the divs on document load while i am storing the data?